# Site-wide CSS updates ruin Android SE badge tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Today, a site-wide CSS update on badge tags took place, to "center" the text & icon on badges which use the "circle" to denote bronze, silver, and gold.

We, on the other hand, use Android logos instead of dots.

**The left padding on all badges increased, making all of "our" badges look off-center.**

Here's what they looked like before:

[image]

**How they look now:**

[image]

---

**Technical details:**

Relevant CSS styling before:

```
.badge-tag {
  padding: .4em .8em .4em .4em;
}
```

And what they changed it to:

```
.badge-tag {
  padding: .4em .8em;
}
```

IMHO, I think our badges look the most centered with a small adjustment from the old version:

```
.badge-tag {
  padding: .4em .8em .4em .5em;
}
```

You can experiment with this by right-clicking on any badge in Chrome or Firefox and going to Inspector, and finding the `padding` attribute in there.

---

This is mainly an issue on the Android SE site, because all of the other sites took this change without much anybody noticing.

Is this is something we'll have to get used to? Or can this be customized (fixed) on our site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've restored the previous style.

Given that it is shared across all sites, I did not make an exception here. Perhaps in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!